# Google Maps Setting Marker Icon Only Duplicates Over Default Icon

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap app that involves Google Maps, and when I load a map and put a marker down on it, I get strange behavior when I set the icon of the marker. Basically, the new image that loads as the icon only loads over the default marker icon. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

This is the code I'm using to change the appearance of the marker:

```
carMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
carMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));

var background = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/parkreminderpop.png",
            new google.maps.Size(100, 90),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
            new google.maps.Point(50, 90),
            new google.maps.Size(100, 90));

var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(photoURI,
            new google.maps.Size(96, 68),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
        new google.maps.Point(48, 88),
        new google.maps.Size(96, 68));

carMarker.setIcon(image);
carMarker.setShadow(background);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this [sample code](http://a32.me/other/gmap/gmap.marker.js) will be helpful for you.

This is the [post](http://a32.me/2011/05/custom-markers-on-google-maps/) related to the above sample code given.

An important thing to remind you is Do not forget to include Google Maps API into your page by adding this single line,

> <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
>   type="text/javascript"></script>

Mejo Wilson

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was up, but the problem seems to have disappeared. Sorry to anyone having the same issue who can't find a solution.